# which join to get entry even if it is not known in other table

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables. users and table2.
In table2 it can have an entry like

```
id = 1
right_user_id = 1
left_user_id = 2
```

in the user table it is possible that there is NO user with id 2.
That means, that the following SQL statement would NOT return the table2-entry with id 1.

```
//php
$sql = 'SELECT t2.*, u.username AS u_name
        FROM users u, table2 t2
        WHERE t2.right_user_id = '.$user_id.'
              AND t2.left_user_id = u.user_id
        ORDER BY t2.time DESC';
```

But I would like to get the t2.* info of the entry with id = 1 anyway and u_name should state "(Unknown)".

What kind of JOIN would I need and how can I do that JOIN?

Comment: I strongly recommend using the explicit JOIN notation illustrated in Juergen's answer (even when LEFT OUTER is not needed).  It is generally superior to the 'comma-separated list of table expressions with joins in the WHERE clause' notation that was required in SQL-86 and SQL-89 but which has been unnecessary since SQL-92 was implemented in your DBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.*, case 
               when u.username is null 
               then 'Unknown' 
               else u.username 
             end AS u_name      
FROM table2 t2
left outer join users u on t2.left_user_id = u.user_id 
where t2.right_user_id = '.$user_id.'     
ORDER BY t2.time DESC;
```